# How to pass javascript variable as url argument

Tags: django

I can't pass javascript variable as the argument to my url. It read the variable as string and instead o variable content it displays variable name. Is there any way to fix it ?

```
const title = movie_info["key"][x]
const image = movie_info["value"][x]["image"]
const single_movie = "<li><span>"+"<a href = '{% url 'reservations' movie="+title+" %}'>"+title+"</a>"+"</span><img src=/media/"+image+"></li>"

path('reservations/<str:movie>', UV.reservations, name='reservations')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use .replace() function

```
const single_movie = "<li><span>"+"<a href = '{% url 'reservations' movie="keyword" %}'>".replace('keyword',title) +title+"</a>"+"</span><img src=/media/"+image+"></li>"
```